# VS code Error : settings.json property expected (bug)

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz0ng.png)

When I use VS Code, a problem notice likes that(in the above image) is printed.
Although I want to fix it and really don't want to see it, I can't find any way to fix.
I am very painful about just seeing that error message all the time.
Please give me some helps.

Answer (score 3):

You opened a `{` parenthesis at line 2784 and didn't close it. You should close it. --> `}`

Also, you have an extra comma `,` at 2793 that you have to **remove**.

Answer (score 0):

Not use `{}`, because you may already mess your `settings.json` before.
so my suggestion as follows:

```
// in/your/settings.json/file
...
setting0_name:[setting0.0, setting0.1],
seting1_name : settings, 
...
```